# How is possible that a MySQL Connection change automatically database?

Tags: c#, database, database-connection

I have done debug step by step with breakpoint so I got this, is so strange:
http://i61.tinypic.com/2nbdhs0.png
At the beginning of the function the database set as default schema is ricette, 
later the calling to open the connection the database as default schema change, look this:
http://i57.tinypic.com/2di4u50.png
the database has changed to "ricette" to "concessionario" but how is possible?
The function OpenConnection() only do this, that doesn't change the db.

```
   public bool OpenConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            return true;
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            switch (ex.Number)
            {
                case 0:
                    MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server.  Contact administrator");
                    break;

                case 1045:
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/password, please try again");
                    break;
                default :
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    break;

            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

So how can I fix that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry but the connectionstring seems to be identical 'concessionario' in both cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the initial connection threw null reference... so it went to the other database. have you updated the password requirements from the first database? your screen shows the first exception was the expired password then null then null then close and returned false. 
and yes the connection sting appears to be for concessario in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed changing the connstring value db